# Make <div> same length and appear in column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styling, markup

I have the following structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='whatStyling'>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='element'>
          <p class='text'>Foo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='element'>
          <p class='text'>Bar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='element'>
          <p class='text'>Fooooooo Baaaaaar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Mark Up

```
#whatStyling {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column,
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.2rem 2.8rem 0.2rem 0.8rem;
  min-width: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.text {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8ansow3/6/

I want to have all elements the same `width`, namely as wide as the longest "box" is (`Fooooooo Baaaaaar`) and appear as column. Note that I need the `display: flex;` on each `.container`. I further do not know how many elements there will be.

What styling would my most outer div `#whatStyling` need, if possible, with `flex box`.

Comment: Do you want full width for foo and bar width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-flex` instead of `flex` then add `width:100%`

```css
#whatStyling {
  display: inline-flex; /*Changed this*/
  flex-direction: column; /* Corrected a typo here*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.2rem 2.8rem 0.2rem 0.8rem;
  min-width: 1rem;
  width:100%; /*Added this */
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.text {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id='whatStyling'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='element'>
      <p class='text'>Foo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='element'>
      <p class='text'>Bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='element'>
      <p class='text'>Fooooooo Baaaaaar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this piece of code. flex-direction is not needed as it is set by default.

```
#whatStyling {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.container {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
Will do the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/g8ansow3/18/

Comment: he want a column direction

Comment: Edited to have column direction.